# Silverlight: Telerik RadGridView CellEditTemplate fetching controls issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik-grid

I am new to the Silverlight. 
At the runtime i am assigning cellEditTemplate to the cell, now when user double click on perticuler cell then it opens that perticuler cell in edit mode. now while entering to the edit mode, I have to fetch the control from edittemplate and need to assign the value. 
But I am not able to fetch that control from edit template.

And main question is that, I don't no where should I write down the code means on which event.

```
col.CellEditTemplate = App.Current.Resources["datatemplate2"] as DataTemplate;
```

In the App.Xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate2">
        <TextBox  />            
</DataTemplate>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the Text of the TextBox to the property of the underlying object as shown in the Telerik online demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/CellEditTemplate